# how to call a flow using SEDA in mule

Tags: mule

I need to implement the SEDA kind of endpoint in mule flow. can anybody tell me some link or example to do this. I have chunk of data that i need to split and call a flow that execute that split data in different threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you arent marking processing strategy as synchronous in the flow then it will use that by default.

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Tuning+Performance

Comment: is there any way that i can do a specific SEDA call in a synchronous flow.

Comment: No, once you have marked processing strategy as "synchronous" flow will not use SEDA queues, it will be just one single thread all the way..

Answer (score 0):

You can use use the queue-async processing strategy within the flow. Reference: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Flow+Processing+Strategies#FlowProcessingStrategies-TheQueued-AsynchronousFlowProcessingStrategySimple

example on SEDA :-

```
<jms:activemq-connector numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers="20" name="Active_MQ" numberOfConsumers="15" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" doc:name="Active MQ">
    <receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="15"/> <!-- for inbound -->
    <dispatcher-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="15"/> <!-- for outbound -->
</jms:activemq-connector>


    <flow name="JMSSender" doc:name="JMSSender" processingStrategy="queued-asynchronous">
        <http:inbound-endpoint  host="localhost" port="8081" path="jms" doc:name="HTTP" exchange-pattern="one-way"/>
        <set-payload value="Test Payload for SEDA model" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <logger message="Payload :- #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="MyQueue" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS"/>
    </flow>


    <flow name="JMSReceiver" doc:name="JMSReceiver" processingStrategy="queued-asynchronous">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="Active_MQ"  doc:name="JMS"  address="jms://tcp:MyQueue"/>
       <!-- other message proccessor -->
    <logger level="INFO" message="Received Payload :-#[message.payload]" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also wrap the flow-ref in an async scope. That way the main flow can still be synchronous, and you call out to do the batch processing in a separate asynch thread, which can then utilize multiple workers if you deploy the app into a Mule cluster (or deploy the application with multiple CloudHub workers).